# Trying to learn $resource. How can I use my own api here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am following the tutorial that can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

In `services.js`, the author has provided the following code to use her own API:

```
angular.module('movieApp.services', []).factory('Movie', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
});
```

I have my own API created with CRUD functions.  I am wondering: how do I use that instead?  The code is located in `/routes/CRUD.js` and the links are `/posts` and `/posts/:id`.

I am confused about whether I need to modify the code of the author with link to my `CRUD.js` or to `localhost:3000/posts/:id`

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Thank you sir Drew for the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('movieApp.services', []).factory('Movie', function($resource) {     
    // post  and pud body data 
    function setRequestData(data) {
        var requestData = new Object();
        requestData.movie= data;
        return angular.toJson(requestData);
    }
  return $resource('localhost:3000/posts/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    }, {      
        'get': {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        },
        'new': {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        transformRequest: setRequestData
        },
        'delete': {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        transformRequest: setRequestData
        },
        'update': {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        transformRequest: setRequestData
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: wow .  Do you think it is better to use $http over $resource if I am going to be doing db writes?  How secure it is to use the $resource?  Thank you sir.  I appreiate your helping.

Comment: $resource is a $http wrapper that allows you to communicate to your api at a higher level, this is the way to go if you ask me